# Javascript If URL has subdirectory

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, parsing, url

Trying to think of an elegant way to remove a subdirectory if a URL contains one and havn't come up with anything. Would love your suggestions. My current implementation has usefulness limited to files at the site's root. Need something more flexible.

The other detail is that it needs to be subdirectory agnostic, so no `.split('nameOfSubdirectory')` business.

To put it in context, I'm using AJAX and am using the target variable to print into the page's url, so I like to make it pretty.

Using the below method, clicking `a[href="otherPage.php"]` returns `otherPage`. If I clicked `a[href="subPage/differentPage.html"]` it would return `subPage`. No go.

```
$('a').click(function(e){

    var thiis  = $(this),
        href   = thiis.attr('href'),
        target = href.split('/')[1].split('.')[0];

    console.log(target);

    /* Does stuff */
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps try assigning the first split operation and then using that result's length as your guide:

```
$('a').click(function(e){

    var thiis  = $(this),
        href   = thiis.attr('href'),
        split_results = href.split('/')[1];
        target = split_results[split_results.length-1].split('.')[0];

    console.log(target);

    /* Does stuff */
});
```

or following this it could be done inline, if somewhat messily.

```
$('a').click(function(e){

    var thiis  = $(this),
        href   = thiis.attr('href'),
        target = href.split('/')[href.split('/').length-1].split('.')[0];

    console.log(target);

    /* Does stuff */
});
```